# How to get Controller Name, customize and find View folder ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

(For education purposes)

I'm trying to change convention ControllerName for render View.

By default, controllers use convention `"Name" + "Controller"`, and then ASP.NET looking for View folder `"Name"`.

I want change this convention. For example: `"Name" + "Foo"`, cut `"Name"` pass and render View folder `"Name"`.

Suppose you need create new convention. `"HomeFoo"` controller must work with View folder `"emoH"` - reversed name controller. For this need take path `"Home"` from controller name, reverse and pass for next operation.

How can this be implemented?

I'm tried implement this with IControllFactory, but I don't know what to do next:

```
    internal class CustomFactoryController : IControllerFactory
    {
  
        public object CreateController(ControllerContext context)
        {
           
            string controllerName = context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName;

            // here reverse Controller name
            // context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName = controllerNameReversed;

            // and next create controller with new Context. How can this be implemented?


        }
        public void ReleaseController(ControllerContext context, object controller)
        {

        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't get me wrong why would you charge the convention? As says don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Maytham, for education purposes)  I was given the task of doing this in order to understand how ASP.NET works from the inside

Comment: You should be looking into IViewLocationExpander  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander?view=aspnetcore-6.0